# unable to deploy an anonymously accessible google apps script webapp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Help!

I am unable to deploy an anonymously accessible google apps script webapp, what am I missing!

from my personal google drive account

> new google apps script
>
> name the project
>
> create a doGet function

```
function doGet(e) {      
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello world!</b>');    
}
```

> Publish > Deploy as webapp > Menu

[image: execute as me; access by anonmous]

> from a logged in user, the content is shown
>
> non-logged in user is presented with Google login

I'm not sure if it will help but here is the [url](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fs%2FAKfycbw72tSzwYXovkvLifLXatCTp_EQuaPBUP9cNw0emRLP%2Fdev&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fs%2FAKfycbw72tSzwYXovkvLifLXatCTp_EQuaPBUP9cNw0emRLP%2Fdev#identifier)

Comment: Dhoooh, thanks, I thought I tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong url.

There are actually **2 urls** : one called the development url (ending with **.dev**) that only the script owner (and editors) can use and that shows the resukt of the last saved script.

And the other one ending with **.exec** that you can send to other users and that will execute the script as saved in the current version. That's actually the most interesting feature of the versioning : you can work on your script without disturbing other users that use the deployed version.

To solve your issue, ensure that you have saved a new version (of a working code) and let other users use that url.

[image]